# Как проверить наличие числа в сериализованном массиве в PHP?

Tags: php, объекты, php7

Подскажите, как в `php` происходит проверка есть ли указанное число в массиве, вот на таком [простом примере](https://onlinephp.io/c/32611) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```php
<?php

$n = "a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;}";  /// gettype() показывает string
                            
$current_user_id = 5; /// integer

array_key_exists($current_user_id,  $n) ? $class_btn_n = 'btn_active' : $class_btn_n = '';
echo '<button class="'. $class_btn_n . '">Button</button>';
```

Не могу понять, почему не отрабатывает [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php)? Пробовал приводить к одинаковым типам и через [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php), но не сработало…

Comment: Что за входной формат? написал комментарий и понял что это не serialize'ом прошлись, и это очень похоже на результат дампа. ну т.е. в вашем коде $n - это действительно не массив а просто строка текста.

Comment: Пробовал unserialize() функцию, но не получилось применить. В $n храниться значение переменных полученных из базы данных.  Выглядят так `a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;}`  Не знаю как в примере показать, это то что выдал var_dump($n)

Comment: Ну функцию вы верную пробовали, и формат который вы привели в комментарии как минимум похож на сериализованые данные, т.е. ```$n = unserialize($n);``` а уже после там будет массив. Если не выйдет - приведите пример входных данных (как он есть в базе)...

Comment: Судя по тем данным что вы привели ваш массив содержит ID пользователя не в ключе а в значении массива, тогда проверка будет выглядеть так: ```$n = "a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;}";$n = unserialize($n); if in_array($n,$current_user_id){echo 'found'}```

Comment: Ок, заменил данные в вопросе. Не знаю как ещё их показать. Вот результат https://onlinephp.io/c/296ba Но он не тот, что ожидается.

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/97409

Comment: А вот так должен был бы выглядеть ваш пример, у вас какой то странный тернарник там :) я его не понимаю :) https://onlinephp.io/c/30010

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Можете оформить ответом. Может кому ещё пригодиться на stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$n = "a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:5;}";
$n = unserialize($n);      
$current_user_id = 5;
$class_btn_n = in_array($current_user_id,  $n) ? 'btn_active' : '';
echo '<button class="'. $class_btn_n . '">Button</button>';
```